# Ubuntu 14.04: How can I set dual screen display correctly with .xprofile?

Tags: 14.04, 64-bit, radeon, amd-processor, multiple-monitors

I am experiencing a **dual monitor problem** using `.xprofile` to change DVI screen resolution.

I am running Ubuntu 14.04.3 Trusty Tahr in dual screen mode. Primary screen output is HDMI; other screen outputs DVI. HDMI output (1600x900+0+0) is not a problem. DVI (1368x768+1600+0) screen causes problem. The DVI monitor is Dell IN1910Nf(2009) DVI-0 1366x768_60.00 which outputs `1024x768 60.0` as highest resolution available (xrandr). So I added a `--newmode` using `xrandr` and created a new `~/.xprofile` file in `/home` dir. But the DVI output changes to 1280x768@60Hz instead of 1368x768@60Hz. Video display does not cover entire screen. `.xprofile` does some thing, but the wrong thing.

---

The `--newmode` config works great per session, but I hoped `.xprofile` would be a permananent fix.

`cvt 1368 768 60` returned... (1366 768 60 returns same)

`1368x768 59.88 Hz (CVT) hsync: 47.79 kHz; pclk: 85.25 MHz`
`Modeline "1368x768_60.00"   85.25   1368 1440 1576 1784  768 771 781 798 -hsync +vsync`

*Added New Mode*:
`xrandr --newmode "1368x768_60.00"   85.25  1368 1440 1576 1784  768 771 781 798 -hsync +vsync`

*Applied New Mode to DVI Port*:
`xrandr --addmode DVI-0 "1368x768_60.00"`

*Applied New Mode to Screen Output*:
`xrandr --output DVI-0 --mode "1368x768_60.00"`

(all of the above works per session)

*Created X profile file in root*:
`gedit ~/.xprofile`

*Added code* to new `~/.xprofile`:
`xrandr --newmode "1368x768_60.00"   85.25  1368 1440 1576 1784  768 771 781 798 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode DVI-0 "1368x768_60.00"
xrandr --output DVI-0 --mode "1368x768_60.00"`

*After OS restarts*, `DVI-0` output changes to "1280x768@60Hz" instead of `xrandr --newmode "1368x768_60.00"` in `~/.xprofile` It does change the resolution, but the size again is wrong.

---

Note: Once `unity-control-center display` settings have been applied, the `xrandr` fix no longer works.

Reference URL:

Ubuntu Wiki - X Config Resolution
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/Resolution

Comment: [Solved] `xvba-va-driver` **XvBA-based backend for VA API (AMD fglrx implementation)** solved my dual-head config problem. `unity-control-center display` named the DVI monitor **Unknown Display** but the correct resolution, **1366 x 768 (16:9)**, was listed in the pull-down menu, which means *fixed* as far as I'm concerned.

Comment: But the output of other resolutions in pulldown menu do not always fill the screen. `xvba-va-driver` installs `fglrx` (proprietary; no updates) without **Catalyst** configuration GUI. `lspci | grep VGA` returns `01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Pitcairn PRO [Radeon HD 7850]`